# interaction of "Foreclosure" and "Crop Insurance" cards

Tags: farmageddon

In the game [Farmageddon](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/102897/farmageddon), if the Foreclosure card is used to "buy" a crop from another player with a Crop Insurance card on it, is the crop acquired complete with the Crop Insurance, or does the Crop Insurance get kept buy the original owner? The Crop Insurance card mentions that it is added to the harvest pile when the crop is "lost"-- and thereby there seems to be an ambiguity: it is "lost" from the point of view of the original player, but otherwise the crop is not "lost" per se.

Answer (score 1):

The way I played was to leave the *Crop Insurance* card to the player to who had played it while the crop ownership was transferred to the other player. Then we played the same rules otherwise where if the crop is destroyed in some fashion then the player who put down the *Crop Insurance* card received the insurance. This would further what I believe was the intention of the card, which is to deter other players from acting on the crop. If they took the crop, the owner of the insurance would have more reason to try to destroy that crop since they would receive their insurance back.

When we played this way, we would have the card facing the owner of the card, so the *Crop Insurance* moves with the crop, but is rotated to face the correct owning player.

I'm unsure if this ruling was read somewhere or if we just locally decided to play it that way.